# Protocol for cross posting when question did not receive any response.

Tags: support, bounty, cross-posting

Recently I've posted a question asking for help to find a numerical optimization algorithm for a given problem.

Here is the question [Optimizing filtering and thresholding parameter before integrating accelerometer data to obtain displacement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301646/optimizing-filtering-and-thresholding-parameter-before-integrating-accelerometer)

I felt the question did not get enough views, so I added 50 reputation points as bounty.

The bounty expired today and I have not even received a single comment or answer.

I am inclined to post the same question on Stack Overflow as there is a programming/implementation part of the problem.

Question: What is the protocol for cross posting question on multiple Stack Exchange site in situations like this? Should I delete math.stackexchange question before posting it on Stack Overflow? Or I can just link to this question here for full disclosure.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo/) for discussion about cross-posting between MSE and MO.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks, I've raised a flag with proper details.

Comment: Note the OP is asking about cross posting to **Stack**Overflow, not **Math**Overflow

Comment: I'd say by all means post to StackOverflow (if that's an appropriate site – I've never been there), but do link the two posts to each other.

Comment: I will add a link to this post - which offers some reasonable advice: [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for "Legitimate" CrossPosting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088) When I looked at older posts taggged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) I found these questions which mention SO - but they do not seem that directly related to your situation: [Questions posted on Math.SE and other SE sites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4168), [Asking a cross-discipline question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12338). (Moreover, both questions are rather old.)

Comment: In case you don’t know: upvotes(downvotes) in meta.MSE indicates (dis)agreement of an opinion. They do not reflect the quality of your post, nor are they counted in your reputation. Personally, I am not seeing in what sense can one disagree about this post, but I suggest there is no need to worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

You asked about choosing a set of four parameters for processing some accelerometer data, with the goal of minimizing disagreement between the accelerometer measurements prediction of location and what a "high precision camera" records as location (or "displacement" to use your term).

You have twelve sessions of experimental data, from which you hope to extract the best parameter set with respect to a least squares error criterion.

The computation applied to your accelerometer data is described at a moderately high level: essentially that the acceleration is integrated twice to provide an offset position.  Both integration steps involve a threshold parameter that is continuous (a floating point number) and a moving average window parameter that is discrete (a positive integer number of steps).

What could the Math.SE Community do to help you?  We could encourage clarification of your goals and your approach.  At this time there is no explicit model to which mathematical reasoning can be applied, though since you have coded something up and gotten an initial set of parameters that gave an acceptable result for at least one session, there surely is a model implicit in your thinking.

What could the StackOverflow Community do to help you?  Putting on our programming hats, there could be suggestions based on the SciPy platform you mentioned, e.g. about constructing a "testing harness" to extensively check various parameter sets against your twelve recorded sessions.  Before asking a new Question there, search for earlier posts that seem relevant.

How about other SE Communities? The one that closely matches your mix of math modelling and coding is [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).  You might have a look at the existing Questions there tagged SciPy.

Given your participation in StackOverflow, I don't expect you would literally crosspost there the Question you asked on Math.SE.  As Gerry Myerson suggested, links between posts could be helpful.

Answer (score -7):

Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  See the general rules on Meta.SE: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

These rules are the default for Stack Exchange sites.  Individual SE sites can set a local policy that overrides that default, if they wish.  If *both* sites allow cross-posting, then you may cross-post as long as you comply with *both* sites' rules. Otherwise, do not cross-post your question on multiple sites -- no matter how long you wait.

Before cross-posting on another site, check their meta to see if they allow cross-posting.  If you can't find anything, then the default Stack Exchange policy applies, and you should not cross-post.

In the case of Stack Overflow, I'm fairly sure they do not allow cross-posting.  So, I suggest you delete the copy here before posting on Stack Overflow.  Make sure you've addressed any feedback you got here.

See also [Is cross-posting the same question to multiple sites not allowed when it is on-topic everywhere?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21237/14578).